# Angular CLI 17 with error Property formGroup is not provided by any applicable directives nor by form element

Tags: angular

So I am trying to create a login form in but I keep getting the error : Property formGroup is not provided by any applicable directives nor by form element.

In the app.module.ts file ReactiveFormsModule is added to the imports list. Have also tried adding the FormsModule in the imports list but I still get the error.

Here is the code of the simple html form

```
    <div class="login-container">
       <div><h6>Login</h6></div>
           <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="onLogin()">
               <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" name="email">
               <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
               <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>

               <button type="submit">Login</button>
           </form>
    </div>
```

Also I had to change to `(submit)`.

And the code for login component

```
 import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

 export class LoginComponent  implements OnInit{

   public loginForm!: FormGroup;
   isLoading: Boolean = false;
   errorMessage!: String;
   infoMessage!: String;
   successMessage!: String;

   constructor(private  fb: FormBuilder) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
       email: ['', Validators.required],
       password: ['', Validators.required]
     });
   }

   public onLogin(){
     event?.preventDefault();
     // show spinner
     this.isLoading = true;


   }

 }
```

What might be the issue ?

Comment: Do you place the `LoginComponent` in the `declarations` array in `AppModule`? Do make sure that the module which your component placed (in the `declarations`) imports both `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`.

Comment: No. I created the LoginComponent as a lazy module ```const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) }

];````

Comment: You need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in `LoginModule` as well